# fancybox not displayed as it should on opera browser

Tags: jquery, fancybox, z-index

i'm using fancybox to display videos when clicking a link but the sidebar videos are on top of the fancybox on opera while all other browsers don't have this problem> please look at this image http://i1026.photobucket.com/albums/y330/yassersharaf/Untitled-1_zpsf903a4e4.jpg
and here's the page address http://www.nubatimes.com please click any of these links to see the problem http://i1026.photobucket.com/albums/y330/yassersharaf/Untitled-2_zpsd5d81f3b.jpg

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: anyways, set `wmode=opaque` to your videos as trailing parameter like `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3l8MwU0IjMI?wmode=opaque`

Comment: It worked you can add it as an answer so I can accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set `wmode=opaque` to your page videos as trailing parameter like

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3l8MwU0IjMI?wmode=opaque
```